# Don't dismiss uialertcontroller sheet with tap gesture outside dialog area in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

in my iOS `swift 3.0` application, I presented `UIAlertController` sheet instance over my current ViewController. But I don't want to dismiss that sheet when I tapped on outside an area of the sheet (dimmed semi-transparent background) because I already have to cancel an action.
Any idea?

I have MGSwipeTableViewCell with more button. When User clicks on that "More" button, following code executes.

```
func onClickMore(for vmCell: VmCell) {
    let sheet = UIAlertController(title: vmCell.vmItem?.vmNameWithoutIp, message: vmCell.vmItem?.ipAddress, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Create Ticket", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Start VM", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restart VM", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Stop VM", style: .destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })

    present(sheet, animated: true) { 
        sheet.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil))
    }
}
```

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632944/any-way-to-prevent-uiactionsheet-from-being-dismissed-when-user-clicks-a-button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466718/uialertcontroller-handle-dismiss-upon-click-outside-ipad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**for UIAlertController Type as alert**

you can download the [**sample project**](https://www.sendspace.com/file/8c3bva)

add the gesture   recognizer to alertController **superview** for handle the userinteraction

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
 alertController.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
})
```

on that action do nothing

**update**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Do something", message: "With this", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { action in
        // perhaps use action.title here
    })

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in


        alertController.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil))
    })
```

**for UIAlertController Type as actionSheet**

you can download the [**sample project**](https://www.sendspace.com/file/xo1akm)

you can do this two ways

**option 1**

```
 alert.view.superview.subviews[0] isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

**option 2**

```
   alert.view.superview?.subviews[0].addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil))
```

for e.g

```
   self.present(sheet, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
    //    sheet.view.superview?.subviews[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
      sheet.view.superview?.subviews[0].addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil))

    })
```

**full code**

```
  let sheet = UIAlertController(title: "karthik", message: "check with", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Create Ticket", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Start VM", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restart VM", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Stop VM", style: .destructive) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })

    sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

    })



    self.present(sheet, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
    //    sheet.view.superview?.subviews[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
      sheet.view.superview?.subviews[0].addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil))

    })
```

Comment: @Sanket - can you update the question, its working perfectly in my side,wait i will attach the sample project

Comment: @Sanket - check the sample project

Comment: i think when you set preferred style = .alertSheet, then it will not wrk

Comment: may i know the downvote reason , check the update answer,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: This will not work when you set the style to actionSheet. In your example you are setting that property to alert.

Comment: @MidhunMP - its works perfectly , I added the sample projects for both ***actionsheet*** and  ***alert*** also, verify once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: It seems like a hack than a solution, it can break in future releases if apple changes it's action sheet view hierarchy. However in current situation it yields the result and I'm retracting my down-vote.

Comment: @MidhunMP - its ok my bro, but UIalertcontroller, there is no public API, for direct handle this, we need to take the view hiearchy , but in future apple changes the hierachy, definitly I will update my answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: There are several other ways, but not perfect ways. 1) If it is in iPad you can use the popover presentation controller delegate to disable the dismissal. 2) In iPhone if you don't specify the action style to cancel it won't dismiss the action sheet when clicking outside, you can set the style to default in that case.

Comment: @MidhunMP - one more question, now you are react the downvote to upvote ,but its not increase the 10 marks in my account how its possible but   it only update +2 marks

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @MidhunMP: Your discussion helps me a lot in understanding the concept.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: Your solution now working Correctly. Thanks again